# How to disable manual entry in gxt DateCell

Tags: extjs, gxt, datecell

How to disable manual entry in DateCell

I am using com.sencha.gxt.cell.core.client.form.DateCell

I want the user to pick the date only from the datepicker and restrict them to enter manually. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any correct approach to achieve your requirement. Below is a workaround/hack to get work done.

```
    DateCell dateCell = new DateCell(){
        public boolean isEditable() {
            return false;
        };
    };
```